# HUD doesn't work with Firefox and Thunderbird

Tags: firefox, thunderbird, hud

I have just upgraded to 12.04 and I have HUD running for many applications apart from Firefox (v14.0) and Thunderbird. I know that this is not default behaviour for many programs, but I have searched around in internet and I see that other people with my distribution version, do have HUD in Firefox. In my case the normal Firefox menus appear, and no Firefox-relevant option shows up in HUD, when hitting the Alt  key.

Does anybody know why is this and how can I solve it?

**Edit**: one the same Ubuntu computer, I used another user account, and I opened Firefox. HUD is working there. So it is a user specific setting

Comment: You should be more specific. Please, add more information to your question, upload a video or something.

Comment: thunderbird 15 seems to work fine in precise with unity 2Ds HUD, I'm having some trouble with Firefox 16 beta though

Comment: the HUD seems to be working fine for me now in both Firefox and Thunderbird in Unity 2D and 3D on 12.04, you might want to make sure you have the firefox-globalmenu and thunderbird-globalmenu packages installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HUD requires that you have global menu enabled.Go to *Tools>Add-ons>Extensions* and enable **Global Menu Bar Integration**
[image: Add-on]
If you don't find this add-on in your list,then you need to install **firefox-globalmenu** and **thunderbird-globalmenu** packages.